# Is there a way to see the expansion of an inline function call?

Tags: common-lisp, inline, compiler-optimization, inlining

Let's take an example :

```
(declaim (inline myinlinefunc))

(defun myinlinefunc (a)
  (* a 2))

(defun myglobalfunc (z)
  (+ (myinlinefunc z) 3))

CL-USER> (trace myinlinefunc myglobalfunc)
(MYINLINEFUNC MYGLOBALFUNC)
CL-USER> (myglobalfunc 2)
  0: (MYGLOBALFUNC 2)
  0: MYGLOBALFUNC returned 7
7 (3 bits, #x7, #o7, #b111)
```

Is tracing the only way to be sure the compiler has inlined the function `myinlinefunc` into `myglobalfunc` ?

Is there a way to see the "expanded" `myglobalfunc` showing inline function calls effectively replaced by there definition, like a macroexpand ?

Comment: How about the [`DISASSEMBLE`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_disass.htm) function? That should show whether there's an explicit call to the function.

Comment: Thanks @barmar, this is effectively a way to see what's actually compiled underneath. But is there a way to "expand" a function like macroexpand, to see its version with calls to inlined functions replaced by their definition ?

Comment: I don't think so, that's not how inlining works. It's done by the compiler at the code generation level, not like macro expansion.

Answer (score 1):

I would expect that the compiler might show you that. Typically an optimizing file compiler.

**Example of a compiler note about code inlining using SBCL**:

Take SBCL and compile the file with the right settings (speed = 3, ...). SBCL then prints a huge amount of compilation information. Among the huge amounts of output the compiler says:

```
;     (MYINLINEFUNC Z)
; --> BLOCK 
; ==>
;   (* A 2)
;
```

This probably tells us about the expansion it uses.